# Ошибки при компиляции: cc1plus.exe:-1: ошибка: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes

Tags: qt, gcc, mingw

Юзаю qt, при выборе компилятора в настройках проекта msvc - все успешно комплится без ошибок, если как компилятор выбираю mingw - компиляция завершается следующей ошибкой: `cc1plus.exe:-1: ошибка: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes`

Comment: Похоже на баг в древней версии gcc: [Out of memory for cc1plus](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/33182613/). Решение - использовать флаг компилятора `-ftrack-macro-expansion=0` или обновить компилятор.

Comment: Помогла смена компилятора